# How to find the frequency of names from files and store the info in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

Here is my `NameRecord` constructor class:

```
public class NameRecord {
    String firstName;
    int count;

    public NameRecord(String name, int count){
        this.firstName = name;
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return firstName + " - " + count + " registered births.";
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

And here is what I have so far of the actual program:

```
public class Names {
    public final int MAX_NAMES = 3;
    NameRecord[] boyNames = new NameRecord[MAX_NAMES];
    String boysFile = "data/boynames.txt";

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = "";
        for (NameRecord record : boyNames)
            result += record + "\n";
        return result;
    }

    public void loadNamesFromFile() {
    try {    
        BufferedReader stream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Data/boysnames.txt"));


        } catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("File not found");
            }
    }
}
```

Basically, the program reads a file and determines if the name is on the boys list or girls list txt files, and then outputs if it is on the list, and if so how many times it was used. I am only working with boys for right now to keep confusion to a minimum. My question is, in the `loadNamesFromFile` method, how do I add information from the file to the `boyNames` array. I know the `NameRecord` calls for the name and the count, but I'm not sure how to retrieve that information from the file and add it to the array. I have included the top three names from the file below, the name is of course the first name and the number is the number of times it was used, or `count`.

```
Jacob 29195
Michael 26991
Joshua 24950
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should add a scanner for the file in order to read what is in the file. After that u keep reading the file and add the information untill there is no more content in the file. Besides this I would use an ArrayList of NameRecord for being more flexible with the number of names.
Im assuming that the content of your file is always the same (given your example).

```
public class Names {
    try {
        ArrayList<NameRecord> boyNames = new ArrayList<>();

        public void loadNamesFromFile() {
            File file = new File("Data/boysnames.txt");    
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
            while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
                boyNames.add(new NameRecord(sc.next(), sc.nextInt()));
            }
            sc.close();
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all if it is possible to have your file structure like this

```
Jacob;29195
Michael;26991
Joshua;24950
```

to make it more easy to develop the solution

and now this is how you can read the file lines and store them into your tabel

```
public void loadNamesFromFile() {
    try {    
        BufferedReader stream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Data/boysnames.txt"));
        String currentLine ="";
        int i = 0;
        while(curentLine = stram.readLine()) {
            String [] record = currentLine.split(";");
            NameRecord = name = new NameRecord(record[0], Integer.parseInt(record[1]);
            boyNames[i] = name;
            i++;
        }


        } catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("File not found");
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to read all the contents of the file i.e., all the names, in a single `String` variable. Then, iterate over each word and count the number of occurrences and add the info to the array. Let's use `Scanner` to read the file.

I presume that the length of the array `boyNames[]` is equal to the number of unique names in the file.

```
Scanner boys = new Scanner(new File("Data/boys.txt"));
int a,i,n=0,c,b;
String con = "", x; //con holds all names
//reading the names
while(boys.hasNext())
    con+= boys.next()+" ";

b = con.split(" ").length; //b = total number of names in the file    
for(i=0; i<b; i++){
    x = con.split(" ")[i];
    if(!x.equals("*")){
        c = 0; a = 0;
        //counting frequency of x in con
        while(con.indexOf(x, a) != -1){
            c++; a = con.indexOf(x, a) + x.length() + 1;
        }
        //adding name and frequency to array
        boyNames[n++] = new NameRecord(x, c);
        con = con.replaceAll(x, "*"); //removing all instances of x from con
    }        
}
```

The `boyNames[]` array now stores the names and their respective frequencies in the file.